# Enable displaying of key strokes without casting

Tags: shortcut

As far as I know you can enable displaying key strokes while you screencast for tutorials.

Is there a way to archive this without casting? I would like to have visual feedback which combos I pressed to make remembering easier.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to download and install the   [screen cast key status tool](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Screencast_Key_Status_Tool) plugin. It has been removed from the Blender download package.

It displays the keys when enabled independently from recording a screencast or normal interaction.